# Unable to determine the principal end of the X relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship

I know there are others who have asked about the same problem, and the answer was to deal with references and not with IDs.

In my case I have a weird behaviour of entity framework : it works in one case (parent-child) but not in the other (child-grandchild).

Here are my models:

```
public class Parent
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}


public class Child
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }       
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<GrandChild> GrandChildren { get; set; } = new List<GrandChild>();  
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }

}

public class GrandChild
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }      
    public Child Child { get; set; }     

}
```

And here's my mapping :

```
public class ParentConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
    public ParentConfig()
    {

        HasKey(e => e.ID);
        Property(e => e.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        HasMany(e => e.Children).WithRequired(c => c.Parent).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentID);

        ToTable("Parent");
    }
}

public class ChildMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {

        HasKey(e => e.ID);

        Property(e => e.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        Property(e => e.ParentID).HasColumnName("ParentID");

        HasMany(c => c.GrandChildren).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.ChildID);
        HasRequired(e => e.Parent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentID);

        ToTable("Child");

    }
}


public class GrandChildMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<GrandChild>
{
    public GrandChildMap()
    {
        HasKey(e => e.ID);
        Property(e => e.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        Property(e => e.ChildID).HasColumnName("ChildID");
        Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        HasRequired(e => e.Child).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ChildID);
        ToTable("GrandChild");
    }
}
```

And here's my code:

```
        Parent parent = new Parent { Name = "Parent", };
        Child child_1 = new Child { Name = "Child 1", Parent = parent };
        Child child_2 = new Child { Name = "Child 2", Parent = parent };
        GrandChild grandChild_1 = new GrandChild { Name = "GrandChild 1", Child = child_2 };
        GrandChild grandChild_2 = new GrandChild { Name = "GrandChild 2", Child = child_2 };

            context.Parents.Add(parent);

            //no need to call SaveChanges

            context.Children.Add(child_1);
            context.Children.Add(child_2);

            //SaveChanges() is needed here

            context.GrandChildren.Add(grandChild_1);
            context.GrandChildren.Add(grandChild_2);

            context.SaveChanges();
```

This code fails with the message

> 'Unable to determine the principal end of the Child_GrandChildren
>   relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key'

But works if I save after adding the child, while I do need to call `SaveChanges()` after adding the parent.

EDIT : if I remove the property `List<GrandChild> GrandChildren` it works, but I really need it.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your relationship configuration in `ChildMap` to this:

```
  HasMany(c => c.GrandChildren).WithRequired(gc=>gc.Child).HasForeignKey(c => c.ChildID);
  // the second one is not necessary, you already configure that relationship in ParentConfig
  //HasRequired(e => e.Parent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentID);
```

Comment: Also remove `HasRequred(...)` line from `GrandChildMap`

Comment: Oh I hadn't scrolled to the end, it's true, the OP is configuring the second relationship twice too.Remove the relationship configuration from the `GrandChildMap` class. Thanks @IvanStoev

Comment: You are welcome @octavioccl. No need to mention you got my +1 anyway :)

Comment: Highly appreciated ;), and congrats  for the 20K @IvanStoev

Answer (score 3):

You should be adding the *Child* objects to the *Parent* object, instead of adding them to the context directly. The *GrandChild* objects should be added to the corresponding *Child* object.

> In this case only the *Parent* object should be added to the context, in this way the entities will be created in the database in the correct order and the FKs will be resolved correctly.

Your code should look something like this:

```
Parent parent = new Parent { Name = "Parent" };
Child child_1 = new Child { Name = "Child 1" };
parent.Children.Add(child_1);
Child child_2 = new Child { Name = "Child 2" };
parent.Children.Add(child_2);
GrandChild grandChild_1 = new GrandChild { Name = "GrandChild 1" };
GrandChild grandChild_2 = new GrandChild { Name = "GrandChild 2" };
child_2.GrandChildren.Add(grandChild_1);
child_2.GrandChildren.Add(grandChild_2);

context.Parents.Add(parent);
context.SaveChanges();
```

If the reference to the added objects is not required, then this *fluent* style initialization code can be used instead:

```
Parent parent = new Parent 
{ 
    Name = "Parent" 
    Children = new List<Child> 
    {
        new Child { Name = "Child 1" },
        new Child 
        {
            Name = "Child 2",
            GrandChildren = new List<GrandChild>
            {
                new GrandChild { Name = "GrandChild 1" },
                new GrandChild { Name = "GrandChild 2" }
            }
        }     
    }
};
context.Parents.Add(parent);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The main issue with adding the child objects to the context directly is that the sequence that should be followed to add the objects to the database cannot easily be inferred, when you declare them like this, especially in the case of the *fluent* logic, the order of operations cannot be confused.

Comment: For OP, the accepted answer is correct, but for everyone who has configured their relationships correctly, this answer targets the next most common reason you will see this error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a final scenario where you can experience this exception, that is when you have recursive or hierarchical relationships.

> When Recursive or Hierachical data needs to be saved with deep links, you should save the data in multiple steps. **Do not be afraid of calling `SaveChanges()` *multiple times***, the overheads are minimal, and for larger sets of data it will actually improve performance to save frequently rather than trying to save as a single action at the end of a process.

> If you are concerned about ACID principals or handling failure and that is why you have avoided calling `SaveChanges()` then you should wrap your logic in a *transaction*:
>
> ```
>   using (var trans = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
>   {
>       ...
>       context.SaveChanges();
>       ...
>       context.SaveChanges();
>       ...
>       trans.Commit();
>   }
> ```
>
> Its not even necessary to catch and handle exceptions if you use the `IDisposable` *using* pattern.
>
> - **NOTE:** Unlike pure SQL, EF does not support nested transactions. You can

In the context of the original post, this might come up if the Parent has a *favourite* `Child` and/or a favourite `GrandChild`:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
    public int? Favourite_ChildID { get; set; }
    public Child FavouriteChild { get;set; }
    public int? Favourite_GrandChildID { get; set; }
    public GrandChild FavouriteGrandChild { get;set; }
}
```

In this scenario it will be important to make sure that the relationships are correctly defined *AND* you will need to save the data in 2 steps.

```
// Parent Config
HasMany(p => p.Children)
    .WithRequired(c => c.Parent)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentID);
HasOptional(p => p.FavouriteChild)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.Favourite_ChildID);
HasOptional(p => p.FavouriteGrandChild)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.Favourite_GrandChildID);                         

// Child Config
HasMany(c => c.GrandChildren)
    .WithRequired(gc => gc.Child)
    .HasForeignKey(gc => gc.ChildID);
```

Saving the data needs to be done in two passes or steps. This model works really well for this. At the start, the `Parent` has no children, later a `Child` is added, at this point, it may not be the favourite...
Later another `Child` is added. Still, the `Parent` has not yet decided who the favourite is. Later a *Favourite* child has been *selected*.

> Lets overlook the real-world fact that having a child is what defines a `Parent` vs a `Person`...

That same thought process needs to be respected by your data logic. If we try to define the child as both the *faviourite* and the *child* of the new parent we have a bit of a conundrum: For the parent object to be saved in the database we need the Id of the Child record, but for the Child to be saved into the database we need the Id of the Parent record... maybe we should have called these `Chicken` and `Egg`...

The solution is to save the *Primary* relationships first, then come back and save any recursive relationship links:

```
Parent parent = new Parent 
{ 
    Name = "Parent" 
    Children = new List<Child> 
    {
        new Child { Name = "Child 1" },
        new Child 
        {
            Name = "Child 2",
            GrandChildren = new List<GrandChild>
            {
                new GrandChild { Name = "GrandChild 1" },
                new GrandChild { Name = "GrandChild 2" }
            }
        }     
    }
};

// using transaction scope here to demonstrate how to manage multiple SaveChanges with a rollback
using (var trans = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    context.Parents.Add(parent);
    context.SaveChanges();

    parent.FavouriteChild = parent.Children.Single(child => child.Name == "Child 1");
    parent.FavouriteGrandChild = parent.Children.SelectMany(child => child.GrandChildren).Single(gc => gc.Name == "GrandChild 2");
    context.SaveChanges();

    trans.Commit();
}
```

> This selection logic won't work if your kids start naming their kids with names that their siblings have decided to use... but you get the point, we should be kind to our Parents as use unique names for out children :)

Or going back to OPs original script. Simply calling `SaveChanges()` in between the assignments, then all of this would have been avoided, using a transaction scope here addresses ACID principals that could be violoated if and exceptions are raised or one of the calls to `SaveChanges()` fails.

```
using (var trans = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    Parent parent = new Parent { Name = "Parent", };
    context.Parents.Add(parent);
    context.SaveChanges();

    Child child_1 = new Child { Name = "Child 1", Parent = parent };
    Child child_2 = new Child { Name = "Child 2", Parent = parent };
    context.Children.Add(child_1);
    context.Children.Add(child_2);
    context.SaveChanges();

    parent.FavouriteChild = child_1;
    // we can save this next time, no Ids need to be forced.

    GrandChild grandChild_1 = new GrandChild { Name = "GrandChild 1", Child = child_2 };
    GrandChild grandChild_2 = new GrandChild { Name = "GrandChild 2", Child = child_2 };
    context.GrandChildren.Add(grandChild_1);
    context.GrandChildren.Add(grandChild_2);
    context.SaveChanges();

    // Now we can assign the faviourite GrandChild
    parent.FavouriteGrandChild = grandChild_2;

    context.SaveChanges();

    // Actually commit the changes to the database
    trans.Commit();
}
```